# Is it possible to disable storage account access keys?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, access-keys

Is it possible to fully disable access with primary/secondary key to the storage account? I have not found a way to do that. It is possible to do e.g. for `Azure SignalR Service`.

P.S. I am not looking to disable shared key access

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? You’re using shared key access when you use account keys. Or by shared key access you actually mean shared access signature?

Comment: I probably mixed something up @GauravMantri, what I want to achieve is to disable all kind of "key" access in favor of Azure AD. I thought primary/secondary keys are not shared access keys

Comment: Please see Vineet's answer below. This is how you can disable access to your storage account by shared access keys (primary or secondary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable shared key access from

1. Azure portal (Settings -> Configuration -> Set "Allow shared key access" to Disabled),
2. Powershell script
3. Azure CLI

See the command below for disabling it using Powershell by setting `AllowSharedKeyAccess` to false.

```
Set-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName <resource-group> `
    -AccountName <storage-account> `
    -AllowSharedKeyAccess $false
```

Read more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/shared-key-authorization-prevent?tabs=azure-powershell)

Comment: Will that disallow usage of primary/secondary keys?

Comment: Thanks a ton! For Az CLI: `az storage account update --name xxx --resource-group xxx --allow-shared-key-access {false, true}`